# Bug on question title element

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Discovered a bug on some question I answered, not sure how to reproduce it, but currently it is visible here:

[Simple Quiz Game JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052214/simple-quiz-game-javascript/39052284)

Title element of the page is:

```
<title>undefined - Simple Quiz Game JavaScript - Stack Overflow</title>
```

Where the 'undefined' should not exist.

Comment: Well, it is a low-quality title in any case. The question is not about "Simple Quiz Game JavaScript". A more honest title would be "I'm getting undefined returned from a function. Figure out why for me."

Comment: @Mike I was thinking the same. This post really begs asking why the title hasn't yet been edited. Ignoring what a poor title "Simple Quiz Game JavaScript" is, tags in titles are discouraged, are they not?

Comment: @CubeJockey 'undefined' is also a tag (as it turns out XD), kinda hard to write a title without any reference to a tag i guess

Comment: @Ziv True, but including some word/name in a descriptive title,which happens to also be a tag, is different from appending a technology-name to the end of a 'title' without any more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a bug.
The question is tagged with: [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined)

Tags are added in the `<title>` element. For example, for this question:

[Recursive function not getting called in nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328440/recursive-function-not-getting-called-in-nested-loops)

The title will show as:

> javascript - Recursive function not getting called in nested loops

Comment: k thanks, didnt see that tag. Still it looks very strange to me.

Comment: Why is [tag:undefined] being picked up as the most relevant tag, though? Isn't it based on the number of questions?

Comment: Because _"JavaScript"_  is already in the title, @Stijn. No point in adding it a second time.

Comment: @ZivWeissman: Strange, maybe. But it makes sense. The tag's name is just a little bit unfortunate.